# Wordpress: Launch a function after login to check if user is a subscriber

Tags: php, wordpress, twitch

I am developing an app in Wordpress. I would like to check after login with OAuth with Twitch TV if a user is a suscriptor of a channel to assign a role. I think it could be done using [Twitch API](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/subscriptions.md) calling an object with the user and then checking if this user is a suscriptor with another GET but if I print $twitchuser and $suscript is void. I am new to PHP, do you know where the mistake or if is there any other approach to do it? My function is included at the end of a `wp-includes/user.php` file:

```
function your_function() {
// Check if the user is Twitch suscriptor

 if ( !is_super_admin() ) {
    $twitchuser = $_GET["https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/user"];
    $twitchname = $twitchuser['name'];

    $suscript = $_GET["https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mychannel/subscriptions/{$twitchname}"];

    if ($suscript == "404 Not Found") {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        // Remove role
        $u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
        // Add role
        $u->add_role( 'nomember' );
    }
 }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function');
```

Comment: At what point are you even making a request to twitch? You probably need to use `curl` if this is not happening in some way you have not disclosed.